# Docker calling unit tests

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

I followed article [getting-started-dotnet-core](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html) and created a class project with XUnit:

```
using Xunit;
namespace MyFirstDotNetCoreTests
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void PassingTest()
        {
            A
```

Then I created a docker image:

```
docker build -t NAME .
```

Question, what docker command can I use to run the unit tests in the class file? Something similar to

```
dotnet test
```

Answer (score 0):

`docker run` command is for run your container. Documentation is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

So if you want to run your tests you can use something like `docker run -it NAME dotnet test`

Comment: Thanks Rudis. I getting the following errors when executing

`$ docker run -it b7a2048336e7 dotnet test
Project dotnetapp (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because the version or bitness of the CLI changed since the last build
Compiling dotnetapp for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
/dotnetapp/project.json(7,48): error NU1001: The dependency dotnet-test-xunit >= 1.0.0-rc2-build10025 could not be resolved.
/dotnetapp/project.json(14,35): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers >= 1.1.0 could not be resolved.
....
....`
    0 Warning(s)
    291 Error(s)

Comment: You have troubles with dependencies which you used. Can you paste here `project.json` file where you defined all dependencies for your priject

Comment: @Joe Hi, did you find the reason for the NU1001 problem? I am facing the very same issue, would appreciate a hint. Thanks.